# How to specify timeout for sending message to RabbitMQ using Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp, spring-cloud-stream

We had an network issue in the middle of sending a message and this was causing all the threads to be in Blocked state. We're using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.0.1.RELEASE`  and `org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.0.8.RELEASE` for sending message to RabbitMQ broker. Binding interface:

```java
interface MessagingSource {
    @Output("bindingTargetName")
    fun messageChannelOutput(): MessageChannel
}
```

Usage:

```java
 val isSent = messageSource.messageChannelOutput().send(message)
```

**MessageChannel#send(Message, long)** method also has the timeout in milliseconds as the second parameter, but it further ignored in **org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel#doSend** method:

```java
@Override
protected boolean doSend(Message<?> message, long timeout) { // timeout is ignored in this method
    try {
        return getRequiredDispatcher().dispatch(message);
    }
    catch (MessageDispatchingException e) {
        String description = e.getMessage() + " for channel '" + this.getFullChannelName() + "'.";
        throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, description, e);
    }
}
```

Can you explain why the timeout parameter is ignored and how i can configure it to avoid long blocking state?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The channel `sendTimeout` only applies if the channel itself can block, e.g. a `QueueChannel` with a bounded queue that is currently full; the caller will block until either space becomes available in the queue, or the timeout occurs.

In this case, the block is downstream of the channel so the sendTimeout is irrelevant (in any case, it's a DirectChannel which can't block anyway, the subscribed handler is called directly on the calling thread).

The actual blocking you are seeing is most likely in the `socket.write()` in the rabbitmq client, which does not have a timeout and is not interruptible; there is nothing that can be done by the calling thread to "time out" the write.

The only possible solution I am aware of is to force close the rabbit connection by calling `resetConnection()` on the connection factory.

Answer (score 0):

One way to protect the code sending the message to RabbitMQ from getting blocked is to wrap the code inside a thread and give it an execution timeout. E.g. the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) class provides a way to specify timeout on invoking the callables