# Spring Cloud Stream - how to handle downstream blocks?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

During a planned downtime for our Kafka cluster, we basically encountered the following issue [How to specify timeout for sending message to RabbitMQ using Spring Cloud Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089800/how-to-specify-timeout-for-sending-message-to-rabbitmq-using-spring-cloud-stream) (with Kafka rather than RabbitMQ, obviously).

The answer from @GaryRussell:

> The channel `sendTimeout` only applies if the channel itself can block, e.g. a `QueueChannel` with a bounded queue that is currently full; the caller will block until either space becomes available in the queue, or the timeout occurs.
>
> In this case, the block is downstream of the channel so the sendTimeout is irrelevant (in any case, it's a DirectChannel which can't block anyway, the subscribed handler is called directly on the calling thread).
>
> The actual blocking you are seeing is most likely in the `socket.write()` in the rabbitmq client, which does not have a timeout and is not interruptible; there is nothing that can be done by the calling thread to "time out" the write.
>
> The only possible solution I am aware of is to force close the rabbit connection by calling `resetConnection()` on the connection factory.

explains quite well why the method in question (`org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel#doSend`) does not take the `timeout` into account. However, this still seems a bit odd to me.

In `spring-integration-kafka-3.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/integration/kafka/outbound/KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:566`, we can see that, if `sync` behaviour is desired:

```java
565    if (this.sync) {
566        Long sendTimeout = this.sendTimeoutExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, message, Long.class);
567        if (sendTimeout == null || sendTimeout < 0) {
568            future.get();
569        }
570        else {
571            try {
572                future.get(sendTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
573            }
574            catch (TimeoutException te) {
575                throw new MessageTimeoutException(message, "Timeout waiting for response from KafkaProducer", te);
576            }
577        }
578    }
```

is called, where a timeout is taken into consideration. The `sendTimeoutExpression` is assigned to a default Value:

```
    private static final long DEFAULT_SEND_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    private Expression sendTimeoutExpression = new ValueExpression<>(DEFAULT_SEND_TIMEOUT);
```

however, our stack trace reveals something different:

```
"pool-1-thread-3" - Thread t@108
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <4ebda621> (a org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture$SettableTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:134)
*   at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.processSendResult(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:572)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:414)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:69)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
```

The invocation marked with `*` corresponds to the `future.get(sendTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` call.

Seeing how the underlying client seems to support it (given by the fact that the `future.get()` call supports a timeout), how this be set? The only two properties I can find in the binder references (see [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html)) are `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.healthTimeout` and `batchTimeout`, which as far as I can tell, do not influence this setting.

Seeing how the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` is constructed in `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler`, a private class, bean overridding is seemingly not the recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be documented, but similar to the listener container customizer https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_consumer_configuration you can add a `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` `@Bean` to set arbitrary properties on the message handler.

In newer versions of the handler, the timeout is always configured to be at least as much as `ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG`, to avoid false negatives (where the publication is successful after the handler times it out).

Comment: Thank you for the information - I'll try to make a PR for the documentation in the next couple days if that's alright. The hint with regard to the `delivery.timeout.ms` setting is also very valuable. Since this is set to `120000` (120s) in the `2.5.1` Kafka Client (what we are using), and the default SCS Timeout is set to `10000` (10s), I guess it would be safe to assume that it we might have had false negatives in the past. I'll try some things out and come back to this answer.